# invoke method of java reflection not updating method at runtime when that method have been changed

Tags: java, reflection

i have a class Demo:

```
public class Demo {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }
    }
```

at runtime i call the method main:

```
    Class cls = Class.forName(packClassName);
    Method thisMethod = cls.getMethod("main", String[].class);
    thisMethod.setAccessible(true);
    thisMethod.invoke(cls.newInstance(), (Object)str);
```

it prints "Hello World!" message. 
Now, after some time i changed the demo class's print message like "Hello java" instead of "Hello World!" and compile the Demo class again. Now again i call the method by same code as above but i can't get updated message. It slill printing "Hello World!"
How do i print updated message. please help me.

Now, i have just done two thing:
 1. Instantiate another fresh ClassLoader instance

```
 cls = Class.forName("anotherClassName");
```

1. Deleted the class file and re-compile it

`boolean success = (new File ("filename")).delete();`

but still not getting updated message... What should i do ?

Comment: delete you .class files and compile again...

Comment: @Frank I delete the class but still not getting updated output...

Comment: is this problem between runs?

Comment: yes, actually i am making my project java compiler. when user edit the program and compile it. It compile well, but when run the program it does not give the updated output and it still showing previous output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the class loader has imported your class, it wont change anymore. As far as I know, there is no way of unloading such a class. As a result, you can't change the class being loaded.

The only way I could think of is if you could instantiate another fresh `ClassLoader`instance that hasn't loaded the class yet.

Check out [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html) and [that](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2003-03/01-qa-0314-forname.html) for more.